# ios 7 - uitableviewCell Separator line

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I need to display separator line in iOS 7 same like iOS 6 (as my image 2). I am using below code in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:229/255.0 blue:229/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_highlighted.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = customColorView;

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

//Separation style for iOS7
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

return cell;
```

I am getting output as below image:

[image]

But my output should like below image for both IOS 6 and 7:

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

`contentView` doesn't always have the same size as the cell itself, add separator view on top of the cell view above the content view:

```
separatorLineView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[cell insertSubview:separatorLineView aboveSubview:cell.contentView];
```

Comment: Thanks@A-Live I have changed it according to you, still getting the same output.

Comment: @user2786 make sure you have both valid width and order at the views hierarchy. Added a bit of code, feel free to ask for details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a property separatorInset. Use that to set the insets of the table view separators to zero to let them span the full width of the screen.

[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

OR

You can set separator inset property in xib also. Change it to custom. And make both left and right values to zero.